# MySQL - photo comments, votes, keywords, ++, in single table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml

I would like to move my photo management system from XML to MySQL and extend functionality of my current system.

Basically, I have few things in MySQL and few in xml files. The situation right now looks like this:

- "**news.xml**" - single file: 
   there are stored all news on my site (new uploads, votes and coments) and the structure of xml is:

  ```
  <all_news>
      <photos>
          <image image_name="photo1.jpg" path="my_photos/" date="12.12.12" info="just Uploaded!" />
      </photos>
      <comments>
          <image image_name="photo1.jpg" path="my_photos/" date="12.12.12" info="just Commented!" />
      </comments>
      <votes>
          <image image_name="photo1.jpg" path="my_photos/" date="12.12.12" info="just Voted!" />
      </votes>
  </all_news>
  ```
- "**photo1.xml**", "**photo2.xml**", "**photo3.xml**" ... - multiple files: 
  These files are created dynamically if someone leaves comment on my photo. For example if someone comment my photo, php script automatically create "**photo_name.xml**" file in format:

  ```
  <comments>
      <comment sender='John' text='nice photo!' who='user' date='22.12.12'/>
  </comments>
  ```
- "**Votes**" - MySQL table: 
   there are stored all votes, and the structure of the table:

  - `id: "photo1.jpg"`
  - `vote: 5`
  - `uid: "IP voting person"`

Now I would like to merge all these things into a single mySQL database table, so each time when photo is loaded - pull these photo informations from single DB table (instead of loading few xml's and DB in same time)...

So my question is:
What table structure is the best in this situation for easiest working on (pull data, move, delete, edit, add, sort...)? 
Should I keep all things for single file in single row using **unique id = "photo.jpg"** and multidimensional arrays? Eg:

```
uid:            photo_name.jpg
path:           my_photos/
isNewPhoto:     array[true, array[info:"just uploaded!"][date:"12.12.12"]] (multi-dimensional array ??)
isNewComment:   array[true, array[info:"just commented!"][date:"12.12.12"]] (multi-dimensional array ??)
isNewVote:      array[true, array[info:"just Voted!"][date:"12.12.12"]] (multi-dimensional array ??)
votes:          1,5,3,2
votesIP:        123123123,123123123,123123123
comments:       array[array[sender][comment][date][who]]] (multi-dimensional array ??)
```

Comment: If you want to use a single table, you'd be better off working with a non-relational system like mongodb.

Comment: Why put everything in one table? You're currently using separate files for news, comments, and votes, so why not replicate that?

Comment: The key feature of the database is that it is relational in nature, having multiple entities with relationships between them. One photo can have many comments, many votes (and voters as well). It makes more sense to build a relational model than to stick everything in one table...

Comment: I gave it a fast try and I realized that keeping everything in a single table is faster to access all data at once, but I didn't realize how fast would be prepare the data to get clean output (yes this require more work)... Keeping data in separate tables will give me same result as I have now (with multiple xml's and sql) so, I'm not realy sure if there's any reason to change anything in my system? What do You think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you CAN actually do that quite easily, when you serialize the arrays before storing their content into a single column. Wether that is a good idea is another thing. Apart from performance issues you give away any chance to make more complex things like search for single attributes.

Why do you insist on a single table ? Even when using multiple tables you can retrieve a single entry combined from multiple table entries with a single query. This gives you much more flexibility for further extensions and use cases.

Comment: Yes good point, You are right that would be very difficult (likely not efficient) implement an searching feature using my scenario... So, I'll stay with multiple tables  (or mongodb mentioned before). Thanks.